# Extracting an object's properties, then splicing it into another object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

I'm pretty new to the JS world, and trying to wrap my head around objects.

Just for a bit of context, my ultimate experiment here is as follows: I have a table, and it displays data gathered from an csv.  This worked well!  Now the next challenge is to duplicate an existing column of this table.  Things fell apart quickly...

I realize that the first thing I need to do is extract the "column" of the table I want to duplicate.  Of course, when I say column I mean the "property" (that just happens to display as the column).

Ok so here's the for loop that isn't working:

```
var namelist = [CSV Data]; // assume it's loaded
var templist = [];
for(var i =0; i < namelist.length; i++) {
   templist[i] = $namelist[i].NAME;
   console.log(templist[i]);
};
```

This just returns a list of names in an array...  I need this as an object that would output something like "NAME: Bob Smith" not just "Bob Smith"...  I figure that the first step is to extract the property/column as it's own object, then inject this property back into the main mix as a new property that applies to every "row"/instance of the object.

It should be noted that this is a nested object, which has a json similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "ATTRIBUTES":"ACTIVE",
    "CODE":"21124",
    "TITLE":"JOB1",
    "NAME":"BOB SMITH",
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTES":"ACTIVE",
    "CODE":"14232",
    "TITLE":"JOB2",
    "NAME":"JOE SHMOE",
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTES":"ACTIVE",
    "CODE":"234234",
    "TITLE":"JOB3",
    "NAME":"MARY JONES",
  }
]
```

After I inject my duplicate it should probably look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "ATTRIBUTES":"ACTIVE",
    "CODE":"21124",
    "TITLE":"JOB1",
    "NAME":"BOB SMITH",
    "NAME2":"BOB SMITH",
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTES":"ACTIVE",
    "CODE":"14232",
    "TITLE":"JOB2",
    "NAME":"JOE SHMOE",
    "NAME2":"JOE SHMOE",
  },
  {
    "ATTRIBUTES":"ACTIVE",
    "CODE":"234234",
    "TITLE":"JOB3",
    "NAME":"MARY JONES",
    "NAME2":"MARY JONES",
  }
]
```

I look forward to your ideas!  Thank you.

PS. I'm working in the AngularJS framework if that helps, probably not as I think this is a pretty "basic" core javascript question.

Comment: That's not a nested object, that' a collection (array of objects). Try looking into `map`, `filter`, and `reduce`.

Comment: Why not use `templist[i] = "Name:"+$namelist[i].NAME;` ?

Comment: Why is everything in caps? If you need caps, use `text-transform` in CSS, don't hard code it into the code.

Comment: @elclanrs, just the way the database itself sent the CSV.  Is it worth lowercasing?

Comment: @jovian, I'm on my phone now but I don't think that would work.  The console indicates that the keys are attributes by i, so it becomes 0: Bob Smith...  I suspect the addition is just going to make it 0: Name: Bob Smith

Comment: @eclnars also thanks for the heads up, my biggest problem is I'm unfamiliar with the vernacular so I have a hard time researching solutions.  I'm going to look those up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a couple helpers. First, as JavaScript objects are passed by reference I would recommend not mutating your original object, so you'll need a helper to extend objects. Then you can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new collection:

```
var coll = [
  {
    attributes:"active",
    code:21124,
    title:"job1",
    name:"Bob Smith",
  },
  {
    attributes:"active",
    code:14232,
    title:"job2",
    name:"Joe Shmoe",
  },
  {
    attributes:"active",
    code:234234,
    title:"job3",
    name:"Mary Jones",
  }
];

function extend(a, b) {
  Object.keys(b).forEach(function(k) {
    a[k] = b[k];
  });
  return a;
}

// @param {Object} props
//   where key is the property to duplicate,
//   and value the duplicate key name.
// @param {Array} a collection
function duplicateProperties(props, coll) {
  return coll.map(function(x) {
    var y = extend({}, x);
    for (var i in props) {
      y[props[i]] = x[i];
    }
    return y;
  });
}

// Usage
var coll2 = duplicateProperties({name: 'name2'}, coll);
```

Also I would suggest not using all caps in your code. If you need to change the formatting of the text do it in your UI code (CSS typically), don't hard code it; it reads poorly, and it's trouble. ALL CAPS in JavaScript is a convention to identify constants. And when you got numbers, make sure you got numbers, not strings. The idea is to polish your data as much as possible from the source, so you don't have to mess with it in the frontend. If the data is already messed up, consider building a simple parser to first transform the data into what you need to work with.

**Edit:**

To clarify `var y = extend({}, x)` clones the current object being looped in the collection, to avoid mutating your original objects. This way you create a brand new collection. `acc` (accumulator) is the new collection, where we're pushing the cloned objects with the duplicated properties.

Comment: OK bro, this is literally blowing my mind here.  I'm a quick learner  but gotta admit I'm very new to this.  Like extend({}, x)... What's going on?  I think what you're doing here is likely brilliant, but in order to truly absorb it so I can use this method more flexibly I would love some more details on what's going on.  Would you mind editing this with more explicit commentary, of the explain it like I'm five type?  Thanks!

Comment: See my edit. Hope that helps. Just need to know that objects are always references, if you want new objects out of old objects you need to clone them.

Comment: Why `.reduce()`? `.map()` would be perfect for this case.

Comment: @package: yes, you're right, I changed to using map.

Comment: This worked!  I had a better look at the code and didn't realize originally that you made your own extend function which confused me because I think there's an object.extend function already out there?

Comment: One last followup, I notice that in {name: 'name2'} that one's a string.  I want to ensure I can be modular with this as the script doesn't know what property is going to be duplicated beforehand (picture drag/dropping a new property over a table)